# How to pass data from a viewcontroller to another tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to clone iOS Note App. I am having an issue with passing data back from Viewcontroller to another Tableviewcontroller. (here from EditorViewController to MainViewController)

I have a Note class with Text and Date properties.

```
class Note: Codable {
    var text: String
    var modificationDate: Date
    
    init(text: String, modificationDate: Date) {
        self.text = text
        self.modificationDate = modificationDate
    }
}
```

TableView:

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var notes = [Note]()

    @objc func createNoteTapped(noteIndex: Int) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditorViewController") as? EditorViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    } 
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...  
    }
}
```

and ViewController that should send Note data back to obove tableview.

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var notes: [Note]!
    var noteIndex: Int!

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    
    func setParameters(notes: [Note], noteIndex: Int) {
        self.notes = notes
        self.noteIndex = noteIndex
        notes.append(notes[noteIndex])
    }
    
    @objc func saveNote() {

     ...

    }

}
```

In the EditorViewcontroller I have a textview , I want to save text inside of it as a Note text, and load that Note into TableView when I tap saveNote. I am really stuck at it, how should I write saveNote function to do that? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Delegate pattern? EditorViewController should have a delegate with method like, func noteCreated(note: Note) and you need to pass ViewController as EditorViewController delegate, I think this answer is answered in several questions

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian , the problem is it gives an error of Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . seems it doesnt save Textview into Note, how to avoid that? should I initialize it something like `notes.append(Note(text: "AAA", modificationDate: Date()))` ?

Comment: You want to pass the notes array or only one array from editor to ViewController?

Comment: @ReinierMelian pass one array back to Tableview.

Comment: then you need to append your newly created note object in your array and after that you need to pass it to delegate through `func updatedNotes(notes: [Note])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in my comments you can create a `protocol` to pass the array of `Note` to your `MainViewController`

```
protocol YourProtocolName {
    func updatedNotes(notes: [Note])
}
```

Then your  `MainViewController` needs to implement this protocol

```
extension MainViewController: YourProtocolName {
   func updatedNotes(notes: [Note]) {
      //Do whatever you need to do here
   }
}
```

After this you need to declare `MainViewController` as `EditorViewController` delegate adding `weak var delegate: YourProtocolName` in your `EditorViewController` class, and lastly you need to modify `createNoteTapped` function in `MainViewController` passing self as `EditorViewController` delegate

```
@objc func createNoteTapped(noteIndex: Int) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditorViewController") as? EditorViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `delegate pattern`, you can use `closures` to pass data back and forward.

in your EditorViewController create the call back closure as like

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController {

        var onCompletion: ((notes: [Note]) -> ())?
        var notes: [Note]!
        var noteIndex: Int!
```

on your save note action set the saved data in the completion part as like

```
@IBAction func saveNote() {
    onCompletion?(notes: notes)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

finally process your data on MainViewController like as

```
   @objc func createNoteTapped(noteIndex: Int) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditorViewController") as? EditorViewController {
         vc.onCompletion = { notes in
        // this will be executed when `saveNote(_:)` will be called
        print(notes)
        // refresh your tableview
    }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: @ramii - please update your code of   func saveNote() { function}

Comment: I did it @Anbu.Karthik its like this now:  `func saveNote() {
        onCompletion?(notes)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }`

Comment: @ramii - okay before sent use optional binding and bind the data to onCompletion?(notes)      its works

Comment: @ramii - is this possible to share your project, I will check